# Edit file from virtual terminal

Tags: command-line, login

I made some mistake in my .profile during adding some path, now I can't  login into my account. All i can do is enter terminal ctrl+alt+f3 and login there. How can I edit from there this file and make everything back to niemal?

Comment: You can use vi editor. Google `using vi editor`

Comment: Use a non-graphic editor, `vi`, `vim`, `ed`, `nano`. You will have to read the `man` page first. Or see if the editor you used left a backup file `~/.profile~`.

Comment: I cant use command vi or even simple ls, it shows error that this command is in /bin and /bin is not in the PATH

Comment: I found solution, I added bin to path by typing export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin then I can use vim.

Answer (score 2):

There are CLI editors available in Ubuntu:

- [nano](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/nano.1.html)
- [vi](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/vi.1posix.html)

If you're unable to simply call nano or vi you can try with absolute paths:

```
/bin/nano .profile
```

or

```
/usr/bin/vi .profile
```

And if you want to bring the default .profile back you can use the template from `/etc/skel/.profile`

```
/bin/cp /etc/skel/.profile /home/yourname/.profile
```